# Set PDF "Initial View" in InDesign CS6?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, pdf

When exporting a document from InDesign CS6 to PDF, is it possible to set the "initial view" of the PDF, so that the PDF opens up in "two up" (side-by-side) format by default?

I can do this in Acrobat.  Can it be done directly in InDesign?

Comment: That doesn't sound like something one could set on document level since it's a client perspective setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Acrobat options in other applications simply aren't as robust as they are in Acrobat itself.

There is no way to set the Initial View options from within Indesign, or Illustrator and Photoshop for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

I have Adobe InDesign CC2019 and what was suggested by User15812 worked. I'm pretty sure it also works with CS6.

**There's something you've got to make sure you get right, and that is that you choose in "Save As Type: Adobe PDF (Interactive)"** 
[image: Save As Type]

By default, the option is "Adobe PDF (Print)"

After you choose "Adobe PDF (Interactive) and click save, you'll be taken to the Export To Interactive PDF dialog window. In there you will find the default "Viewing" options. These will work whenever someone opens a document.

[image: Export to Interactive PDF Dialog Window]

Answer (score -3):

`file` > `export` > `pdf` (interactive)
and choose initial view.

Comment: Please can you explain what that should do? Only the command sequence is perhaps not understandable for all readers ...

Comment: I tried to export the pdf with the way described above, but in that case I could not apply the required job options. Does this mean that we cannot combine standard job options with Initial View options?